# Posting a FollowResult object returns a HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: json, rest

When i post my follower object to my rest call i get a 415 error but i dont see why? I did not add the private fields of the dao's and other value's becaus its a biger file i only put the code of the calls and client and http handler in this post.

Error message:

Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://localhost:8080/KwetterBart-web/api/user/startfollow
Response Code : 415
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://localhost:8080/KwetterBart-web/api/user/startfollow

Here are my classes :

Method that receive my rest call i think the problem is something with the consumes of this method:

```
@Path("/startfollow")
    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml","text/xml"})
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response startfollow(FollowResult result) {
        User user = Userdao.FindUser(result.username);
        if (user != null) 
        {
            List<User> followers;
            followers = user.getFollowers();
            User followuser = Userdao.FindUser(result.follow);
            followers.add(followuser);
            user.setFollowers(followers);
            Userdao.edit(user);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("succes", "User changed");
            return Response.ok(jsonObject.toString()).build();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObjectRequest = new JSONObject();
        jsonObjectRequest.put("error", "Cannot get a user");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(jsonObjectRequest.toString()).build();
    }
```

Class for httphandler:

```
public static String sendPost(String url, String body) {
        try {
            URL oUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) oUrl.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            os.write(body.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());

            in.close();

            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Client side that post the code to my rest service:

```
private void Startfollow(ActionEvent event)
    {
        FollowResult user = TableFollow.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(user.getUsername()); 

        String loginuser = TFUsername.getText();

        FollowResult follower = new FollowResult(user.getUsername(),loginuser);

        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            HttpHandler.sendPost("http://localhost:8080/KwetterBart-web/api/user/startfollow",gson.toJson(follower));
            this.getfollowers(loginuser);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(KwetterFollowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

Object class of FollowResult i have this class on my client side and on my server side:

```
public class FollowResult {

    String username;
    String follow;

    public FollowResult(String username, String follow) {
        this.username = username;
        this.follow = follow;
    }  

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFollow() {
        return follow;
    }

    public void setFollow(String follow) {
        this.follow = follow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the FollowResult object your DAO?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following two annotations to your FollowResult class on the server site.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="followresult")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
```